# C# external web service requires timestamp

Tags: c#, web-services, timestamp, soapui

Your help is much appreciated.

I am trying to automate a web service call using C#. I managed to get it working from SoapUI. The service call requires authentication with valid username/pw as well as timestamp. But I don't know how to add this timestamp to C# service call.

Details of the web service.

1. URL: https://prod.decisionpoint3.com/fleet/bsm/api/JobExecutionService?WSDL
2. Authorization Basic
3. Credentials. Username:xxxx, Password:xxxx
4. **In SoapUI, under Outgoing WS-Security Configurations, Add Username using the credential above and then add Timestamp, with Time to Live as 60**

Details of request from SoapUI

1. request - getJobExecutions, raw XML as below

[image: show image]

To Automate I created a C# Console application, added web reference as Veda. Code snippet as below

```
        string username="xxxx";
        string password="xxxx";
        Veda.JobExecutionServiceImplService service = new Veda.JobExecutionServiceImplService();

        System.Net.NetworkCredential credential=new NetworkCredential(username,password);

        service.Credentials=credential;
        service.Timeout = 1000;

        Veda.JobDefinitionKey jobDefinitionKey=new Veda.JobDefinitionKey();
        jobDefinitionKey.jobName="xxxx";
        jobDefinitionKey.serviceFQN="Enterprise/Consumer/Term/ConsumerTermBusinessService";
        jobDefinitionKey.templateName="ConsumerTermAUDataExtractCRM";

        Veda.executionDateTimeRange executionDateTimeRange = new Veda.executionDateTimeRange();
        executionDateTimeRange.startSpecified = false;
        executionDateTimeRange.endSpecified = false;

        Veda.JobExecution[] executions=service.getJobExecutions(jobDefinitionKey, executionDateTimeRange);
        foreach(var exe in executions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exe.id);
        }
```

My code threw an Service Access Violation exception because of this missing timestamp information.

your help in pointing the direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a custom binding with includeTimestamp="true"?

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for the help. I did try but still didn't work. The same error.